# Trying to find window manufacturer from sticker on vinyl window

Tags: windows

I have a bottom sash of a vinyl window with some broken glass and need to replace it.  There are several stickers and markings on the window, but I am not able to figure out who manufactured the window.  I've attached pictures of the stickers/markings that I found.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check out Milgard - send your picture to them: www.milgard.com. Given that date - it looks like new home construction - your home builder really should know who made those windows - they usually have a BOM for quite some time - like 8 years or more - I had questions answered by my builder after 10 years!

Answer (score 2):

If you know who the home builder was you may be able to get in touch with them.  Generally they will know which company they went with...if that isnt possible depending on the age of the window you may be able to take it to a builder's supply or big box store and get an answer.

All that said replacing a window pane is generally pretty easy and most hardware/big box stores will cut the glass to size for you.  If it is double pane that could be a little more tricky.

Comment: Agreed, the manufacturer might not even re-glaze it for you and only sell you a new window package. Take the frame out and cover the opening for a few days while the glazing company you take it to in your area, fixes it (bring the sticker so they can match the glass).